# Cuanto espacio ocupa un null en la base de datos

Tags: mysql

buenos días el motivo de mi pregunta es mas informativo es sobre el espacio que ocupa un campo null en la base de datos, ya que tengo una base de datos con varios campos  y en algunas ocasiones  me queda varios campos en null y me preocupa sobre el espacio que puede tener ese campo null en mi base de datos, ya que no quiero desperdiciar la memoria de mi servidor al momento de implementar la base de datos, cuando consulto sobre la información sobre el tema  encuentro mucha información contradictoria me gustaría saber en donde puede encontrar información confiable sobre el tema, además pues estoy utilizando Mysql como motor de base de datos
adjunto un ejemplo de mi base de datos [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no soy muy bueno con la base de datos cualquier información o corrección sobre el tema sera recibida con mucho agradecimiento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Los campos con tamaño variable ocupan 1 byte para indicar que es NULL.**

*Los valores nulos no se guardan en el propio campo sino en la cabecera del registro. En dicha cabecera hay un puntero para cada campo. Si el puntero es nulo, el campo tiene valor nulo.*

**Los campos con tamaño fijo, sean NULL o no, ocupan lo mismo**

*int - 4 bytes*