# llenar campos necesarios?

Tags: mysql

tengo que evaluar unos examenes mediante 2 tecnicas pero no de manera paralela, con eso quiero decir que cada tecnica tiene sus propios parametros entonces debera existir aveces los parametros 1...5 o parametros 6...8 pero es recomendable almacenar solo los paratros que existiran y dejar en blanco los demas campos?

+---------parametros------+

```
parametro 1
parametro 2
parametro 3
parametro 4
parametro 5


parametro 6
parametro 7
parametro 8
```

+------------------------------+

Comment: @RubenHernandez esta bien puedes responder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te refieres a guardarlos la verdad es que a la larga no porque aunque sean nulos necesitan cierto espacio, yo lo haría en tablas separadas o con un campo de tipo en la misma tabla

Eje campos

id,nombre,parametro,calificacion

"parametro" seria el valor que usaría para hacer la validación en la vista

Mira que curioseando me tope con este post de cuanto pesa un campo nulo
[Cuanto espacio ocupa un null en la base de datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109750/cuanto-espacio-ocupa-un-null-en-la-base-de-datos)

Saludos :)